# Removing numpy array columns with the same non-missing value, when missing values present

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, missing-data

I have a numpy array from which I need to remove columns which have the same value for non-missing cells, and remove columns with all values missing.
The array:

```
>>> x = np.array([[ 1.,  2.,  2., np.NaN,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 2., np.NaN,  1., np.NaN,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [np.NaN,  1.,  1., np.NaN,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2., np.NaN, np.NaN,  2., np.NaN,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1., np.NaN,  2., np.NaN,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., np.NaN,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [np.NaN,  1.,  0., np.NaN,  2., np.NaN,  2.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  1., np.NaN,  2.,  2.,  1.]])

>>> x
array([[ 1.,  2.,  2., nan,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 2., nan,  1., nan,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [nan,  1.,  1., nan,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2., nan, nan,  2., nan,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1., nan,  2., nan,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., nan,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [nan,  1.,  0., nan,  2., nan,  2.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  1., nan,  2.,  2.,  1.]])
```

I can remove the column with all values missing (column index 3)

```
>>> x[:, ~np.all(np.isnan(x), axis=0)]

array([[ 1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 2., nan,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [nan,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2., nan,  2., nan,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  2., nan,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [nan,  1.,  0.,  2., nan,  2.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.]])
```

I can remove all columns where there is the same value in all rows (column index 4)

```
>>> x[:, ~np.all(x[1:] == x[:-1], axis=0)]

array([[ 1.,  2.,  2., nan,  2.,  1.],
       [ 2., nan,  1., nan,  2.,  1.],
       [nan,  1.,  1., nan,  2.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2., nan, nan, nan,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1., nan, nan,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., nan,  2.,  1.],
       [nan,  1.,  0., nan, nan,  2.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  1., nan,  2.,  1.]])
```

but, how do I remove column 6 (index 5) where the non-missing values are the same, but presence of missing values messes up with the boolean check?

EDIT: Desired outcome

```
array([[ 1.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 2., nan,  1.,  1.],
       [nan,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2., nan,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [nan,  1.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could chain several masks using bitwise operators. You basically need two masks.

- One for the `NaNs`
- One to check if the first row values are equal to the rest of the column

Then chain both conditions with a bitwise `OR`, and check if `all` rows satisfy the conditions:

```
m1 = np.isnan(x)
m2 = x[0] == x
x[:, ~(m2|m).all(0)]

array([[ 1.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 2., nan,  1.,  1.],
       [nan,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2., nan,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [nan,  1.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```